# spark custom Aggregator >=2.0 (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I have following Dataset:

```
val myDS = List(("a",1,1.1), ("b",2,1.2), ("a",3,3.1), ("b",4,1.4), ("a",5,5.1)).toDS
// and aggregation
// myDS.groupByKey(t2 => t2._1).agg(myAvg).collect()
```

I want to write custom aggregate function `myAvg` which takes Tuple3 arguments and return `sum(_._2)/sum(_._3)`.
I know, that it can be computed in other ways, but I want to write custom aggregate.

I wrote something like that:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

    val myAvg =  new Aggregator[Tuple3[String, Integer, Double], 
                                Tuple2[Integer,Double], 
                                Double] {
      def zero: Tuple2[Integer,Double] = Tuple2(0,0.0)
      def reduce(agg: Tuple2[Integer,Double], 
                 a: Tuple3[String, Integer,Double]): Tuple2[Integer,Double] = 
                              Tuple2(agg._1 + a._2, agg._2 + a._3)
      def merge(agg1: Tuple2[Integer,Double], 
                agg2: Tuple2[Integer,Double]): Tuple2[Integer,Double] = 
                              Tuple2(agg1._1 + agg2._1, agg1._2 + agg2._2) 
      def finish(res: Tuple2[Integer,Double]): Double = res._1/res._2
      def bufferEncoder: Encoder[(Integer, Double)] =
                              Encoders.tuple(Encoders.INT, Encoders.scalaDouble)
      def outputEncoder: Encoder[Double] = Encoders.scalaDouble
    }.toColumn()
```

Unfortunately I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.apply(Column.scala:217)
```

What's wrong?

In my local Spark 2.1 I receive one warning

```
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
```

What is deprecated in my code?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: One minute later... However, the error message was correct ...
The problem was in `column()` => `column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem here is your use of Java's `Integer` instead of Scala's `Int` - if you replace all usages of `Integer` in your Aggregator implementation with `Int` (and replace `Encoders.INT` with `Encoders.scalaInt`) - this works as expected:

```
val myAvg: TypedColumn[(String, Int, Double), Double] =  new Aggregator[(String, Int, Double), (Int, Double), Double] {
  def zero: (Int, Double) = Tuple2(0,0.0)
  def reduce(agg: (Int, Double), a: (String, Int, Double)): (Int, Double) =
    (agg._1 + a._2, agg._2 + a._3)
  def merge(agg1: (Int, Double), agg2: (Int, Double)): (Int, Double) =
    (agg1._1 + agg2._1, agg1._2 + agg2._2)
  def finish(res: (Int, Double)): Double = res._1/res._2
  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[(Int, Double)] =
    Encoders.tuple(Encoders.scalaInt, Encoders.scalaDouble)
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Double] = Encoders.scalaDouble
}.toColumn
```

(also applied some syntactic sugar, removing explicit `Tuble` references).